# Google Fonts API Security Warning in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, google-webfonts

I am using the Google Fonts API on a site that I am developing.

While the API is working fine on all browsers including IE8.

The problem is that in IE8 it gives a security alert.

I add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>` in the header but still the issue persists.

![Below the is the link to the security alert that I get.][1]

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4bXA.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw this question after a long time and realised no one answered, so let me myself answer it for someone help.

The security warning alert that we were getting on IE8 was because the application was under development on our local servers while we were fetching the fonts from Google server, which meant cross-domain origin for the font files.

This led to security warning in IE8.

Now that the site is live, there are no more alerts.